# Duplicate Method Names - Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why does this compile with out any errors or warnings?

```
@interface ObjectTest : NSObject {

}
-(void)iAmADoubleMethod;
-(void)iAmADoubleMethod;
@end

@implementation ObjectTest
-(void)iAmADoubleMethod {
    NSLog(@"IAmADoubleMethod");
}
@end
```

I came across this in a project I am working on. I come from a C++ background, so I figure I would get at least a warning for this. Not only would I like to know why it complies but could this code cause any problems?

Thanks.

Comment: I'll put this as a comment because I'm not sure it's correct but: I believe this works because the C standard says you can have any number of declarations so long as there is only one definition.  for eg, you can declare an int x in many files, but you may only define space for the variable in one place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're just declaring the method twice. The declarations don't conflict, so it's not a problem. It's the same as if you'd declared a function multiple times in a plain C or C++ program.

Comment: Thanks, maybe one day I will read the standards.  Probably not :)